# Rails - Problem rendering an helper method in another helper method in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I have 2 methods like this in my user_helper.rb

```
def full_name(user)
  if user.last_name?
    user.first_name + " " + user.last_name
  else
    user.first_name
  end
end

def user_info(user)
  full_name(user)
  user.city
 end
```

And in the view

```
<%= user_info(current_user) %>
```

It renders well the city, but not the full_name I've tried with html_safe also but It doesn't work. COul you explain me why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the implicit function return only covers the `user.city` part, you'd have to concatenate the two strings if you want to display them both.

```
def user_info(user)
  full_name(user) + ' ' + user.city
end
```

Comment: Work well, Thanks a lot for your explaination!